# Determine if a string contains only alphanumeric characters (or a space)

Tags: c++, string, iterator

I am writing a function that determines whether a string contains only alphanumeric characters and spaces. I am effectively testing whether it matches the regular expression `^[[:alnum:] ]+$` but without using regular expressions. This is what I have so far:

```
#include <algorithm>

static inline bool is_not_alnum_space(char c)
{
    return !(isalpha(c) || isdigit(c) || (c == ' '));
}

bool string_is_valid(const std::string &str)
{
    return find_if(str.begin(), str.end(), is_not_alnum_space) == str.end();
}
```

Is there a better solution, or a “more C++” way to do this?

Comment: I don't see what's not C++'ish with this. You mind telling us?

Comment: @Mads: You see, I'm not sure whether it is C++ enough! I'm coming from a C background and each time I ask a question and provide my "too C and not enough C++" code, I get murdered.

Comment: Well, murder *back* then. There is nothing wrong with this code at least. C++ is a multi-paradigm language where no style is more correct than the others. Anyone who try to tell you differently, don't know what they're talking about. If you like metaprogramming, use templates. If you like procedural programming, use the bare bone features like function overloading. If you like OO-code, use inheritance. Or mix and match.

Comment: But do use RAII instead of explicitly managing resources and exposing yourself to leaks.

Comment: I also would like to avoid double negation: use `find_if_not` and rename function to `is_alnum_space` and remove the `!` of the return

Comment: @56ka: at the time, `find_if_not` was not available (it's C++11).

Comment: You are right, anyway it was helpful ;)

Comment: char c might be negative and isalpha etc require input to be >= -1 && < 256. So your solution is NOT correct.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Looks good to me, but you can use `isalnum(c)` instead of `isalpha` and `isdigit`.

Comment: +1. Also you can use `isspace()` if you want to count other types of whitespace (e.g. tab).

Comment: The only suggestion that I have for improvement is to not have `_not_` in function names as it can make for unreadable code. Consider this instead: `return find_if(str.begin(), str.end(), is_alnum_space) != str.end();`

Comment: @Johnsyweb: That won't work though. That will return `true` for a string that contains *at least one* alphanumeric+space character, but I want to ensure that they are *all* alphanumeric+space characters. The purpose of the `find_if` is to find the first element that satisfies the predicate, the predicate being "not alphanumeric or space". If we get `str.end()` we know that no character satisfied that predicate, so they must all be alphanumeric or space characters.

Comment: @dreamlax: You are right. It has clearly been a long week :-)

Comment: @Johnsyweb If you want it more readable use find_if_not instead ;)

Answer (score 10):

And looking forward to C++0x, you'll be able to use lambda functions (you can try this out with gcc 4.5 or VS2010):

```
bool string_is_valid(const std::string &str)
{
    return find_if(str.begin(), str.end(), 
        [](char c) { return !(isalnum(c) || (c == ' ')); }) == str.end();
}
```

Comment: The syntax is initially confusing, but I'm sure I'll get used to it.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!! +1!

Comment: Just pass "" to the function on input and it would insta-throw at C++ runtime level (MS Runtime at least).

Comment: There literally seems to be an assert checking for the byte to be above 0... lol? straight within isctype.cpp used by isalnum() and isctype.cpp and debug data for that file are not even available from MS debug servers.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with binders so you can drop the helper function.  I'd recommend [Boost Binders](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/bind/bind.html) as they are much easier to use then the standard library binders:

```
bool string_is_valid(const std::string &str)
{
    return find_if(str.begin(), str.end(),
        !boost::bind(isalnum, _1) || boost::bind(std::not_equal_to<char>, _1, ' ')) == str.end();
}
```

Comment: Wow that is crazy and cool at the same time. Although, I don't what to check for all types of whitespace, I just want to check for the space character itself. Is that still possible with binder?

Comment: @dreamlax - yes, that's possible.  I've updated the answer to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Minor points, but if you want is_not_alnum_space() to be a helper function that is only visible in that particular compilation unit, you should put it in an anonymous namespace instead of making it static:

```
namespace {
bool is_not_alnum_space(char c)
{
    return !(isalpha(c) || isdigit(c) || (c == ' '));
}
}
...etc
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, what is the benefit of this anonymous namespaces over using static functions?

Comment: It's deprecated by current c++ standards for this use.

Answer (score -1):

In case dont want to use stl function then this can be used:

```
     // function for checking char is alphnumeric
   bool checkAlphaNumeric(char s){
        if(((s - 'a' >= 0) && (s - 'a' < 26)) ||((s - 'A' >= 0) && (s - 'A' < 26)) || ((s- '0' >= 0) &&(s - '0' < 10)))
           return true;
        return false;
           
    }
    
    //main 
    String s = "ab cd : 456";
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        if(!checkAlphaNumeric(s[i])) return false;
    }
```