# How to check if a string is all lowercase and alphanumerics?

Tags: c++, string, lowercase, alphanumeric

Is there a method that checks for these cases? Or do I need to parse each letter in the string, and check if it's lower case (letter) and is a number/letter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [islower()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/islower), [isalnum()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isalnum) to check for those conditions for each character. There is no string-level function to do this, so you'll have to write your own.

Comment: Good point. I've edited this to reflect that. I didn't know about that function.

Comment: Am slightly confused here, you commented your own answer with 'Good point...'

Comment: @t0mm13b there was a comment before I made mine, pointing out isalnum(). I guess it's been deleted :P

Comment: @unwiseguy you can always [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187754) by clicking the checkmark by the answer. Upvoting is the one that requires 15 reputation.

Comment: No.. you still have to wait x-amount of minutes after you post a question to accept an answer, but thanks

Comment: See my answer -- there actually *is* a string-level function to do this, though it's not where most people would probably expect to find it.

Comment: @JerryCoffin cool. I didn't know that. Your answer should be the accepted one.

Comment: @Oleksi: I'm perfectly fine with yours having been accepted -- although the function does exist, I'm not at all sure I'd recommend using it. I'm pretty sure most people will find something like `islower` or `isalnum` in a loop or passed to `std::find` much easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the "C" locale is acceptable (or swap in a different set of characters for `criteria`), use `find_first_not_of()`

```
#include <string>

bool testString(const std::string& str)
{
      std::string criteria("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789");
      return (std::string::npos == str.find_first_not_of(criteria);
}
```

Comment: Assumes "C" locale (which might not matter to the OP).

Comment: @bgporter Sorry for this reply nearly two years later, but how efficient is this method? I'm working on a Chemistry equation balancer and this seems like an ideal pre-check instead of performing multiple checks per character.

Comment: I guess the question is 'efficient compared to what?'. My first choice is to assume that the standard library is in general going to be fast enough (and relatively bugfree) compared to handwritten code.

Comment: @Andrue it won't be very efficient, because `std::find_first_not_of` needs an internal loop to check if the element is not in the set, unlike `isdigit`, `isalnum` and `islower` which can use just a few comparisons depending on locale

Answer (score 3):

It's not very well known, but a locale actually *does* have functions to determine characteristics of entire strings at a time. Specifically, the `ctype` facet of a locale has a `scan_is` and a `scan_not` that scan for the first character that fits a specified mask (alpha, numeric, alphanumeric, lower, upper, punctuation, space, hex digit, etc.), or the first that doesn't fit it, respectively. Other than that, they work a bit like `std::find_if`, returning whatever you passed as the "end" to signal failure, otherwise returning a pointer to the first item in the string that doesn't fit what you asked for.

Here's a quick sample:

```
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {

    std::string inputs[] = { 
        "alllower",
        "1234",
        "lower132",
        "including a space"
    };

    // We'll use the "classic" (C) locale, but this works with any
    std::locale loc(std::locale::classic());

    // A mask specifying the characters to search for:          
    std::ctype_base::mask m = std::ctype_base::lower | std::ctype_base::digit;

    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        char const *pos;
        char const *b = &*inputs[i].begin();
        char const *e = &*inputs[i].end();

        std::cout << "Input: " << std::setw(20) << inputs[i] << ":\t";

        // finally, call the actual function:
        if ((pos=std::use_facet<std::ctype<char> >(loc).scan_not(m, b, e)) == e)
            std::cout << "All characters match mask\n";
        else
            std::cout << "First non-matching character = \"" << *pos << "\"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I suspect most people will prefer to use `std::find_if` though -- using it is nearly the same, *but* can be generalized to many more situations quite easily. Even though this has much narrower applicability, it's not really a lot easier to user (though I suppose if you're scanning *large* chunks of text, it might well be at least a little faster).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the tolower & strcmp to compare if the original_string and the tolowered string.And do the numbers individually per character.

(OR) Do both per character as below.

```
#include <algorithm>

static inline bool is_not_alphanum_lower(char c)
{
    return (!isalnum(c) || !islower(c));
}

bool string_is_valid(const std::string &str)
{
    return find_if(str.begin(), str.end(), is_not_alphanum_lower) == str.end();
}
```

I used the some info from:
[Determine if a string contains only alphanumeric characters (or a space)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926878/determine-if-a-string-contains-only-alphanumeric-characters-or-a-space)

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`std::all_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of)

```
bool lowerAlnum = std::all_of(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), [](const char c){
    return isdigit(c) || islower(c);
});
```

If you don't care about locale (i.e. the input is pure 7-bit ASCII) then the condition can be optimized into

```
[](const char c){ return ('0' <= c && c <= '9') || ('a' <= c && c <= 'z'); }
```

Answer (score -1):

If your strings contain ASCII-encoded text and you like to write your own functions (like I do) then you can use this:

```
bool is_lower_alphanumeric(const string& txt)
{
  for(char c : txt)
  {
    if (!((c >= '0' and c <= '9') or (c >= 'a' and c <= 'z'))) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```