# C++ cout prints out same string a few times

Tags: c++, if-statement

My code has an if else statement which verifies whether an input is a string full of alpha characters.

The code works but the `cout << original << "\n";` part prints out the result 5 times. I think the root of the issue lies within the `for (std::string::iterator it=original.begin(); it!=original.end(); ++it)` line, specifically the `++it` bit.

Below is the code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int nNumberofArgs, char* pszArgs[])
{
    std::locale loc;
    std::string original;
    std::cout << "Welcome to the English to Pig Latin translator!\n";
    std::cout << "Type a word you wish to translate:\n";
    std::getline(std::cin, original);
    std::cout << "Your word: " << original << "\n";
    for (std::string::iterator it=original.begin(); it!=original.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (original.length() > 0 && std::isalpha(*it,loc) )
        {
            std::string word;
            std::transform(original.begin(), original.end(), original.begin(), ::tolower);
            cout << original << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Please enter a valid word." << std::endl;
        }
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

This link is a screenshot of my CLI output:
http://gyazo.com/5b9cea385794fecc39ed578b539a84c3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not correct. It checks for each character rather than the entire string.

Change it to:

```
bool alphaString = true;
for (std::string::iterator it=original.begin(); it!=original.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (! std::isalpha(*it,loc) )
        {
            std::cout << "Please enter a valid word." << std::endl;
            alphaString = false;
            break;
        }
    }
if ( alphaString ) {  
  std::transform(original.begin(), original.end(), original.begin(), ::tolower);
  cout << original << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's printing five times because "hello" is five characters long. Your for loop is running once for each character in the string.

Comment: Ah, okay! The reason the for loop is involved is because that's the only example in which I know how to execute the `isalpha` part of the code. If I did it without the for loop and just used the if/else statement and used `...&&isalpha(original))` the Dev-C++ compiler doesn't like it.

Comment: If you want to see if the entire string is alpha-numeric or similar, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926878/determine-if-a-string-contains-only-alphanumeric-characters-or-a-space