# Distinguishing between numbers and other symbols [c++]

Tags: c++, string, parsing, double, text-files

I'm reading a text file and extracting pieces of information of it by means of parsing (line by line).
Here is an example of the text file:

```
 0    1.1       9     -4
 a    #!b     .c.     f/ 
a4   5.2s   sa4.4   -2lp
```

So far, I'm able to split each line using empty spaces `' '` as separators. So I can save, for example, the value of `"1.1"` into a string variable.

What I want to do (and here is where I'm stuck) is to determine if the piece of information that I'm reading represents a number. Using the previous example, these strings do not represent numbers: `a  #!b  .c.  f/  a4  5.2s  sa4.4  -2lp`
Alternatively, these strings do represent numbers: `0  1.1  9  -4`

Then I would like store the strings that represent numbers into a double type variable (I know how to do the conversion to double part).

So, How can I distinguishing between numbers and other symbols? I'm using c++.

Comment: How about using regular expressions?

Comment: Look it up on the internet.

Comment: you may want to look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926878/determine-if-a-string-contains-only-alphanumeric-characters-or-a-space

Comment: @kuisf-rund You can use regular expressions to search for patterns in text.

Comment: You could try casting it to a double and if that fails just keeping it as a string

`try
{
    double x = mystring;
}
catch()
{
    string x = mystring;
}`

Comment: @SamyBencherif: You can try that, but it'll fail miserably. The only cast in C++ that you normally expect to throw an exception is `dynamic_cast` (which won't work here).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
// check for integer

std::string s = "42";

int i;
if(!s.empty() && (std::istringstream(s) >> i).eof())
{
    // number is an integer
    std::cout << "i = " << i << '\n';
}

// check for real

s = "4.2";

double d;
if(!s.empty() && (std::istringstream(s) >> d).eof())
{
    // number is real (floating point)
    std::cout << "d = " << d << '\n';
}
```

The `eof()` check makes sure that the number is not followed by non numeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a current (C++11) compiler, the easiest way to handle this is *probably* to do the conversion using `std::stod`. You can pass this the address of a size_t that indicates the location of the first character that could not be used in the conversion to double. If the entire input converted to double, it will be the end of the string. If it's any other value, at least part of the input didn't convert.

```
size_t pos;
double value = std::stod(input, &pos);

if (pos == input.length())
    // the input was numeric
else
    // at least part of the input couldn't be converted.
```